# How to Get Responce from Google News in JSON instead of XML

Tags: android

I want to get responce in json from google news insteed of xml when i hit

https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=hi_in&hl=hi&output=rss

Comment: and why not to use the [the Google feeds api](https://developers.google.com/feed/?hl=fr)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert this **php** class to a **java** class easily and use it:

```
<?php
 **
 * Google-News feed parser and JSON provider Class
 *
 * @package None
 * @author Nuhil Mehdy <nuhil@nuhil.net>
 */
class GoogleNews {
 
    public $searchQuery = 'Good News';
 
    public function __construct ($searchQuery) {
            if(!empty($searchQuery)) {
                    $this->searchQuery = $searchQuery;
            }
 
            $this->numberOfNews = 5;
    }
 
    public function __toString() {
            return $this->getNews();
    }
 
    public function setSearchQuery($searchQuery) {
            if(!empty($searchQuery)) {
                    $this->searchQuery = $searchQuery;
            }
    }
 
    public function setNumberOfNews ($numberOfNews) {
            if(!empty($numberOfNews)) {
                    $this->numberOfNews = (int) $numberOfNews;
            }
    }
 
    public function getNews () {
            return $this->processNews();
    }
 
    private function processNews() {
            $loadXml = simplexml_load_file(urlencode('http://news.google.com/news?q='.$this->searchQuery.'&num='.$this->numberOfNews.'&output=rss'));
 
            $news = array();
 
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($loadXml->channel->item as $item)
            {
                preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@', $item->description, $match);
                $newsSections = explode('</pre>
', $item->description);
 
 $news[$i]['title'] = (string) $item->title;
 $news[$i]['image'] = $match[1];
 $news[$i]['link'] = (string) $item->link;
 $news[$i]['news_source'] = strip_tags($newsSections[1]);
 $news[$i]['short_story'] = strip_tags($newsSections[2]);
 
 $i++;
 }
 
 $result = array('news' => $news, 'status' => '200', 'message' => 'OK');
 
 return json_encode($result);
 }
 
}
?>
```

this class parses and transforms **rss** feeds output to **json** format, you can find the whole post on [Nuhil personal website](http://nuhil.net/2013/07/12/get-google-news-as-json-by-parsing-rss-feed/), good luck.

**Note:**
may be some response output fields in this example doesn't exist anymore, so you have to check the format of the response items and adjust your class in consequence

Comment: android not support php

Comment: I know, that's why i suggested to you to try converting this class to java class